# How to store password in a field using openerp

Tags: odoo-8

In my database 15 users are have their login and password. If any user change their password then we don't know the users current password. I want to save the password of each users that admin have the only permission to view.If any user changed their password, then admin can know their password, because if we want to login with particular user then it results wrong password. 
or
when I login to odoo there is no option to save the password, the username is restore but I want to keep the password automatically fill in the field, does anybody know how to do it?
  Thanks........

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to save a password unencrypted in your database.
I'd suggest to take a look at the [auth_admin_passkey](https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/8.0/auth_admin_passkey/) module.
This would give you the possibility to login at all useraccounts with the admin password.

If you really want to save the new password you could override the write method from res.users and check for the field "password". this way you could save the password to your desired field before it gets encrypted.